# Postfix how to use policy service together with proxy filter

Tags: postfix

Using postfix 2.9 on debian I have configured before-queue proxy filter for scanning of spam and viruses `smtpd_proxy_filter=127.0.0.1:27`. I am using proxy filter and not content filter, so that I can directly reject the email (with after-queue content filter, I can only discard the email and optionally send backscatter to forged sender address).

I also want to use policy service to limit the number of sent emails per SASL username. This is configured in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` just before `permit_sasl_authenticated`. The policy daemon works OK, but postfix complains that it cannot HOLD the email with this message:

```
warning: access table inet:127.0.0.1:10031: with smtpd_proxy_filter
specified, action HOLD is unavailable
```

As per this [thread](https://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=120453509106007&w=2), this is not directly possible:

> To HOLD mail with smtpd_proxy_filter, specify the HOLD action with the
>   smtpd proces AFTER the filter.

I have tried that, however when I put the policy service on the smtpd daemon after the proxy filter (smtpd on port 26 in my case), it doesn't get any SASL information (confirmed with tcpdump).

```
smtpd :25 ---> before-queue proxy localhost:27 ---> smtpd localhost:26
```

So how can I combine these two checks?

EDIT: Maybe nested before-queue filters would work? Then I would need to use different program for the SASL checks, or make some filter/policy protocol rewriting...

Comment: Also from the filter it is not possible to HOLD the email (only reject, accept, discard), so I can now only think of determining the HOLD condition in filter, adding special header and uses access map in the AFTER smtpd to HOLD based on this header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have been able to come up with solution which works fine, although it is a two-step approach.

First, I have modified the policy daemon (postfix cluebringer v2) configuration to return the **PREPEND** directive instead of HOLD. I am adding a special header, which will be evaluated later: `PREPEND X-cust-policy: Hold`. This works even with combination with before-queue proxy filter.

Second, I used the directive [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)`pcre:/etc/postfix/header_hold` in the `main.cf` to check for my added later. This check is avaluated by the [`cleanup(8)`](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html) daemon before the mail enters the queue. So after the email is passed via all checks including policy daemon, it is passed through the before-queue filter and then it is processed by the [`cleanup(8)`](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html) daemon. Normally it should put the message into the *incoming* queue, but when it finds this header, the mail is put directly into the *hold* queue.

Here is the contents of [PCRE table](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) file `/etc/postfix/header_hold`:

```
### PCRE format, no postmap command!
# Hold all email with specified header (which is inserted by policy service)
/^X-cust-policy: Hold/    HOLD
```

The only caveat is that the header-based check will also trigger on returned undeliverable mail (but it doesn't happen often that email released from *hold* queue will be bounced back).

Also I had to update cluebringer webui to support the PREPEND action for Quotas module, although the daemon itself supports it already (the version in Debian wheezy).